# React - too much recursion

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

I'm still almost new to `react`. When I open my webpage the console shows me this:

> Too much recursion

I actually cannot find the reason where the error comes from.
What I already determined is, that the error occurs when I'm using the component `CreateFreightEntryModal`. If I uncomment this in the `FreightList` component, the error disappears.

Here is the code for both the components. Maybe someone of you can find the recursion.

**FreightList.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Freight from './Freight';
import CreateFreightEntryModal from './CreateFreightEntryModal';
import createFragment from 'react-addons-create-fragment'; // ES6

class FreightList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: "",
            freights: [],
            parent: props.parent,
            updateZonesTable: props.updateZonesTable
        };
        this.loadFreights();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    }


    loadFreights() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          context:this,
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          url: "../data/get/json/freight",
          data: ({ 
              _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
          }),
          success: function (data) {

              var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { 
                return el; 
              });

              this.setState({
                freights: arr
              });

          }
      });
    }

    handleFreightClick(freight, isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            $('#freightListPanelBody').collapse();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                context:this,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                url: "../data/post/json/zones/getZonesByFreightId",
                data: ({ 
                    _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                    freightId: freight.id,
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    this.props.updateZonesTable(data, freight);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    updateSearch(event) {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0,20) })
    }

    onClose(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    openCreateModal(event) {
        $('#createFreightEntryModal').modal();
    }


    onClick() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel-group">
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <a className="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#freightListPanelBody"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Freights</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body" id="freightListPanelBody" className="collapse in">
                        <div className="row padding10px">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.openCreateModal.bind(this)}>Create new entry</button>
                                    <CreateFreightEntryModal onClose={this.onClose.bind(this)} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row padding10px">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                Search
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.search} placeholder="Search" onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row padding10px">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <div className="table-responsive list">
                                    <table className="table table-hover table-striped" id="freightListTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                ...
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                ...
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        {
                                            this.state.freights.map((freight) => {
                                              return (
                                                <Freight freight={freight} onClick={this.handleFreightClick.bind(this)} key={freight.id} />
                                              );
                                            })
                                        }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FreightList
```

**Freight.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Freight extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            freight: props.freight,
            onClick: props.onClick,
            isChecked: false
        };
    }

    onClick(event) {
        $('#freightListTable').find("input").removeAttr("checked");
        this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked})
        this.props.onClick(this.state.freight, !this.state.isChecked);
    }

    render() {
        return (

                <tr className="cursorPointer" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                ...

                </tr>

        );
    }
}

export default Freight
```

**CreateFreightEntryModal:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SelectOption from './SelectOption';

class CreateFreightEntryModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            freights: props.freights,
            onClose: props.onClose,
            onClick: props.onClick,
            companies: [],
            freighttypes: [],
            transportmodes: [],
            hauliers: [],
            warehouses: [],
            countries: [],
            placesOfDeparture: [],
            products: [],
            productgroups: [],
            suppliers: [],
            currencies: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.state = {
            companies: [],
            freighttypes: [],
            transportmodes: [],
            hauliers: [],
            warehouses: [],
            countries: [],
            placesOfDeparture: [],
            products: [],
            productgroups: [],
            suppliers: [],
            currencies: []
        }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
        /*
        if(nextState.companies) {
            this.setState({
                companies: nextState.companies,
            }, this.render);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
        }
        */
    }

    loadCompanies(event) {
        if(this.state.companies == undefined || this.state.companies.length == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                context:this,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                url: "../data/get/json/companies",
                data: ({ 
                    _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                }),
                success: data => {
                    var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                    this.setState({
                        companies: arr
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }

    loadFreightTypes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/freightTypes",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    freighttypes: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadTransportModes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/transportModes",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    transportmodes: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadHauliers() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/haulier",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                filter: "noStopFlag",
                value: "0",
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    hauliers: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadWarehouses() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/warehouses",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                filter: "noStopFlag",
                value: "0",
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    warehouses: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadCountries() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/countries",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    countries: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadPlacesOfDeparture() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/placesOfDeparture",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    placesOfDeparture: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/products",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken, 
                filter: "noStopFlag",
                value: "0",
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    products: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadProductGroups() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/productgroups",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken, 
                filter: "noStopFlag",
                value: "0",
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    productgroups: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadSuppliers() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/suppliers",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken, 
                filter: "byBrancheAndStopFlag",
                branche: "2",
                stopFlag: "0",
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    suppliers: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    loadCurrencies() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/currencies",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken, 
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    currencies: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    add(event) {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal fade" id="createFreightEntryModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 className="modal-title">New freight entry</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <form onSubmit={this.add.bind(this)}>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <strong>Create a new freight entry:</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                Company
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                                <div className="form-group" onClick={this.loadCompanies.bind(this)}>
                                                    <select className="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-id="selectBoxCompany" data-live-search="true" data-title="Please select" ref="Firma" required>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.companies.map((company)=> {
                                                          return (
                                                            <SelectOption value={company.Nummer} displayValue={company.Bezeichnung} key={company.id} />
                                                          );
                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        ...

                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CreateFreightEntryModal
```

The freight list is loaded via ajax request. Here is a sample of one freight entry:

[image: freight entries list]

The complete freight list consists of 539 freight entries.

The line number is this:

[image]

Comment: any indication from the error - like a line number - where this occurs

Comment: Usually, this occurs when there is a setState in componentDidUpdate. And the setState causes recursive updates (no stop condition).

Comment: I've updated the original post with the line number, but I'm not sure if this helps...

Comment: That is far too much code for us to even attempt to reproduce your problem. It’s actually impossible since you are depending a lot on remote services. Please attempt to reduce your code to the *minimum* that still causes this error. – For debugging purposes, you should add logging to your methods, so you can see what code still runs fine and what runs last before the error. That way you can locate surely the problem.

Comment: In `CreateFreightEntryModal`, why are you assigning `this.state` in the constructor to prop values, and then immediately in `componentWillMount` you replace all that with empty values?

Comment: Is `componentWillMount` not called before the constructor and not otherwise? But I think, I can remove this codepart now.

Comment: No, the constructor is called as the very first thing when an instance of a class is called. That is a language feature. `componentWillMount` is a React-specific lifecycle method of the component which runs later after the instance has been created.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error. It was in the `SelectOption` component.
There was like @vijayst said a `componentDidUpdate` recursion.
Thanks for the hint!